# Long path name in SetCurrentDirectoryW

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Using [this msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) I created a small use case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{

    const std::wstring dir_path = L"\\\\?\\c:\\temp\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory\\ThisIsPrettyLongNameForDirectory";

    if (!CreateDirectoryW(dir_path.c_str(), NULL))
    {
        std::cout << " Error occurred while creation of directory!!!  " << GetLastError() << std::endl;     
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Lenth is " << dir_path.length() << std::endl;

        if (dir_path.length() > 255)
        {
            if (!SetCurrentDirectoryW(buf.c_str()))
            {
                std::cout << " Error occurred!!!  " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << " Successful!!!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

However, I get the output as

```
Error occurred while creation of directory!!!  3
```

[Error code 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) points me to

```
ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
3 (0x3)
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Are there any other way to use long path names in CreateDirectoryW or SetCurrentDirectoryW APIs that I am unaware of ?

PS:I am using VS 2015 Update 3 compiler on Windows 7.

Comment: SetCurrentDirectory is a unixism that is still pretty heavily restricted by the MAXPATH limitation.  One that wasn't removed until Win10 version 1607.  That requires explicit opt-in, given that it is so likely to cause stack buffer corruption in code that you didn't write, it is explained well in the MSDN docs for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create each directory on the path one by one. So the parent directory to the directory you pass must exist before you call [`CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855.aspx).

This information can be found by reading the documentation. It specifically calls out that error code and says:

> One or more intermediate directories do not exist; this function will only create the final directory in the path.

Comment: I'm sorry to sound condescending, and I know that documentation is sometimes imperfect, but you really must get into the habit of reading it closely.

Comment: On command prompt, `mkdir mylongpath` with long name prefix (i.e \\?\) did not work. I simply get error saying filename or extension is too long on. Isnt there a unix equivalent `mkdir -p` in Windows ?

Comment: I think my answer addresses the question that you asked, or does it not?

Comment: I think I will have to manually create the path until its of acceptable length and then create inner directories until the length of complete path crosses 255 characters and beyond.

Comment: You can do exactly what I said. Create each directory along the way until you've done it all.

Comment: Yes. Tried that and failed after 243 characters.

Comment: What failed? Creating the directories?

Comment: " So the parent directory to the directory you pass must exist before you call CreateDirectory" ....I understand that parent directory must exist before I create an inner directory. If I use mkdir from command prompt how is that incorrect ? Its irrelevant if I create a directory using mkdir command or using GUI or C++ code since the end goal is to use the long name prefix so that path is accessible. Kindly clarify. I wonder why my question is down voted.

Comment: The question asks about an error calling `CreateDirectory`. In your comments you ask about `mkdir`. I've answered your question.

Comment: @Recker: Your question is down-voted, because it's of the *"Please read the documentation for me"* type of questions. And frankly, down-voting an answer, that **fully** answers the question you asked, just because you don't like its author is childish, and against all rules established for this site. Pretty tough not to call you something that will have my account suspended. Anyway, grow up. Or die trying.

Comment: @IInspectable I shall pretend that I did not read your comment. Whether I use mkdir or C++ API is still irrelevant and it does not answer my question. I am trying to create a directory with long path name and then I am trying to access it. If creation of directory is itself failing in the first place ,I dont understand how I would be able to access it ?

Comment: @Recker: Apparently you are a big fan of skipping the documentation. It **explicitly** points out the error code you receive, and explains, what needs to be done to fix it. Not sure what else there is to be said.

Comment: @Recker `mkdir` and `mkdir -p` just call out to `CreateDirectory()`; they don't do anything special. In the case of `mkdir -p`, the `mkdir` program just splits the path apart and make all the intermediate directories; this is a simple loop that shouldn't be too hard to write yourself. If you're just typing `mkdir \\?\C:\Whatever` in your command line you *might* be falling victim to some shell backslash expansion thing (but I don't really know). Either way, it all boils down to the same `CreateDirectory()` function you are using.

Comment: @Recker of course, if `CreateDirectory()` works but `SetCurrentDirectory()` does not, then please read Hans Passant's comment above. And please stop antagonizing the people who are trying to help you; be calm, clear, and explicit with what you want out of them. The way you are acting right now makes people not want to provide further help; sorry. And remember that MSDN is your friend.

Comment: @andlabs Both mkdir/mkdir -p and CreateDirectoryW did not work for me. Your comment "If you're just typing `mkdir \\?\C:\Whatever` in your command line you might be falling victim to some shell backslash expansion thing (but I don't really know)." has solved the mystery that I have been trying to fathom. I ll dig about this further. Also, I am just exercising my choice of using shell commands instead of reinventing a loop that does the same thing. Profound apologies to all the moderators. Never meant to antagonize anyone. I shall put more clarity in my questions henceforth.

Comment: `CreateDirectoryW` can create long directories just fine. Works perfectly here. You aren't in control of what mkdir is doing. Is it prefixing with `\\?\` when it calls the API? You don't know. But you can control the call to `CreateDirectoryW` and that does, and always has done, supported long paths.