# Error 206 in SetCurrentDirectoryW

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

After my [previous unclear question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389617/long-path-name-in-setcurrentdirectoryw), I was somehow able to create a directory with a long path name. However, if I try to access it by adding a long path name prefix, it still throws an error as follows.

```
ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE
206 (0xCE)
The filename or extension is too long.
```

Here is the code snippet that I am using (On Windows 7 with VS 2015 Update 3 compiler)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    const std::wstring wdir_path (L"\\\\?\\c:\\temp\\aLongPathnameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent\\aLongPathNameComponent");

    if (!SetCurrentDirectoryW(wdir_path.c_str()))
    {
        printf("SetCurrentDirectory failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Next, I tried running this on Windows 10 with version greater than 1607 as mentioned in the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx), I set the registry key and rebuild the above code but when I run it, I still I get the same error. I have read the documentation multiple times and I not sure what is it that I am doing wrong here. Can anybody please point me in the right direction ?

**Update**

1) Here is the manifest file that I used for Windows 7

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
        <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

I also added a new DWORD value in the registry key as mentioned in 2). However, on Windows 7, it just doesnt work.

2) On Windows 10, the registry key method worked. I modified following registry key as per the documentation

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD)
```

If I disable this, it fails and vice versa.

Comment: Yes I did set the manifest entry and the registry key.Still no luck. Does that mean that SetCurrentDirectoryW support for long path names is broken ? Just curious.

Comment: Long path name restrictions were relaxed with Windows 10, version **1607**. Is *"1606"* just a typo in your question? Can you include your manifest file as well? Also, heed the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530.aspx): *"The final character before the null character must be a backslash ('\')."* @DavidHeffernan: The documentation explicitly calls out, that you can enable long path awareness for this particular API, starting with Windows, version 1607. Is the documentation wrong, or are you referring to a different restriction?

Comment: @IInspectable Added updates to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, this will succeed if your manifest is specified correctly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ....I might get banned from SO for asking this but my workplace peers are still questioning me as to why the above snippet fail to work on Windows 7 ? [MSDN documentation of SetCurrentDirectoryW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx) says that it should ideally work. Any comments ?

Comment: The docs are perhaps a little confusing. But for this function, you can only remove path limitation on Windows 10, version 1607.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as modifying the registry, you must include the `longPathAware` setting in your application manifest. That is described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath):

> You can also enable the new long path behavior per app via the
>   manifest: XML
>
> ```xml
> <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
>     <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
>         <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
>     </windowsSettings>
> </application>
> ```
>
> These are the directory management functions that no longer have
>   MAX_PATH restrictions if you opt-in to long path behavior:
>   CreateDirectoryW, CreateDirectoryExW GetCurrentDirectoryW
>   RemoveDirectoryW SetCurrentDirectoryW.

The manifest that is found in your question is invalid. The `application` element should be inside `assembly`.

```
<!-- language: xml -->

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
      <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

Finally, any mention is Windows 7 is missing the point. The `MAX_PATH` limitation can be removed from Windows 10 1607 only.

Comment: The previous version of the cited reference was misleading. It made it appear as if the manifest modification was optional. They have corrected it now: _"The application manifest must also include the longPathAware element."_

Answer (score 4):

The MSDN documentation for this function is unusually bad. Most functions that take a path as input will allow you to bypass the `MAX_PATH` restriction by prefixing the path with `L"\\?\"` but this function is not one of them. If you look at a [older version](https://web.archive.org/web/20141221011005/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx) of the documentation you will see that `MAX_PATH` is the documented limit no matter what you do on Windows 8 and older.

When the new long path policy was added in Windows 10 (1607) most functions got a note about this added in the documentation in a gray shaded box and this functionality is a relaxation of the \\?\ prefix that already existed in the documentation but for this function both the policy and the \\?\ are new but only the policy is in a gray box with the version information, the \\?\ prefix is part of the normal description so it looks like it has always been there but it was in fact documented at the same time as the policy!