# How to change the current directory to a long path

Tags: winapi

Although it is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) to handle the `\\?\` prefix, `SetCurrentDirectory()` apparently isn't able to do this ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519069/1197719)). Passing a path that is longer than 260 characters always returns `ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE` even though I included the `\\?\` prefix. Tested on Windows 7.

This makes me wonder how I can change the current directory to a path that is longer than 260 characters. Do I have to break that long path down into pieces of max. 260 characters each and call `SetCurrentDirectory()` on each of those pieces, or what is the recommended way of dealing with this problem?

NB: I know that on Windows 10 the problem can be solved by setting adding the `longPathAware` stuff in the manifest and setting the corresponding registry flag. However, I'm specifically looking for a solution that works on Windows 7 and 8 as well.

Comment: use the "current directory" think not good idea at all. for what this ?

Comment: Does it work to call SetCurrentDirectory repeatedly as you describe?

Comment: @RbMm: It's a Windows backend for a cross-platform toolkit so I need to provide this function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Tried it now, and unfortunately, it doesn't work. So I guess there's no way at all to change the current directory to a path that is longer than 260 characters?

Comment: 0x104 (256) hard-coded inside `SetCurrentDirectory` so you can not resolve this. even on win10. win32 still very bad support long paths. if you will use nt function - no any problems

Comment: What NT function can I use to replace `SetCurrentDirectory()`?

Comment: @RbMm: *bump* ... you make it sound like I could just use an NT function to work around the `SetCurrentDirectory()` 256 char limitation. Is that right or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Andreas - no, i mean that if use nt functions ( like *NtOpenFile, NtCreateFile*) you can use any path length (up to 32k charasters) even on nt 4.0. no any problems here. and you can use absolute or relative paths here too. this api much more power clear and simply (from my view) compare win32 layer. but in case *SetCurrentDirectory* - nothing can be done even on windows 10 - 260 hardcoded limit here

Comment: The docs for [SetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) do suggest that it should work.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes, that's what I mentioned in the OP. But it doesn't work. I've tried it and you can try it for yourself. Also see the link I posted in the OP where somebody else confirms that the documentation is wrong. RbMm also seems to have taken a look at the disassembly to confirm that it doesn't work. So it's very likely a documentation bug.

Comment: Are you using SetCurrentDirectoryW, in your code? SetCurrentDirectoryA does not support long paths.

Comment: @Nickd'Alterio: Yes, of course I'm using `SetCurrentDirectoryW()`, as documented on MSDN. But the documentation is wrong (see above). It doesn't work. Even on Windows 10. If anybody on here has gotten `SetCurrentDirectoryW()` to work with long paths (as documented on MSDN), please step forward and say "here".